# Is there a shell simulator

Tags: unix, ksh

Is there a KornShell (ksh) simulator for practicing commands?

Comment: Use the shell... it's as good as it gets. Anyway, to what purpose, what is preventing you from using the shell?!

Comment: actually i m very new to shell.. so just looking for something to practice on...

Answer (score 5):

You don't want a simulator, run the real thing (it's tiny!).

On debian/ubuntu etc, `apt-get install ksh`

On windows, install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com), then see http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2008-05/msg00283.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to practice the shell and you're seriously unsure of your abilities, you may wish to create a new user account for testing. That way you reduce the chances of accidentally removing your entire photo library or music library or source code. :)

`adduser` or `useradd` on most Linux systems, though most distros have GUIs to guide you if you'd rather.